# Inaccuracy in fftw calculation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, vtk, fftw, itk

I am calculating the fft of an image which pixels are double with the FFTW library, for that purpose i am using the library fftw(http://www.fftw.org/) library in Visual Studio 2008 and using ITK (http://www.itk.org/).

When I calculate the fft from a double pointer, with the method  ‘fftw_plan_dft_c2r_2d’, it makes the calculation but introducing inaccuracy, it is around +- 0.5…

I don’t really know what is wrong, maybe the spacing between pixels? The type of the data used? Did someone have this problem or something similar before?

Many thanks in advanced.

Antonio

CODE:

The code is here:

```
// FFT CALCULATION
    // Inizialization of the neccesary elemnets for calculating the FFT. 
    fftw_plan p1;  //variable for storing the FFT 
    int N_fft= ancho*alto;  //number of points of the image
    fftw_complex *F1 =(fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*alto*((ancho/2)+1));  // result pointer
    p1 = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(alto,ancho, f1, F1, FFTW_ESTIMATE);  // FFT planning
    fftw_execute(p1);  // FFT calculation
    fftw_destroy_plan(p1); // plan is destroyed
```

I want to do the FFT to double pointer called f1.

Comment: How are you determining that there is an inaccuracy ?

Comment: I compare the result with a Matlab calculation :)

Comment: OK - can you edit your question to include the part of your code where you create the FFTW plan and execute the FFT itself ?

Comment: OK - I don't see anything obviously wrong - how big is the *relative* error, i.e. for a +/- 0.5 error what are the absolute values in each case. Also what are the values of your image dimensions (alto and ancho) ?

Comment: The absolute values are in the range of 0 to 200 aprox. And the image dimensions are 640x480

Comment: OK - and the image dimensions ?

Comment: Alto ( high) is 480 pixels, and ancho(width) is 640.

Comment: I know this question is old but what type of data is `f1`? Is it of type `double[2]` or just `double`? If it is of type `double` then it isn't the correct input type for FFTW. It requires `fftw_complex` which is a typedef of `double[2]`.

Comment: Hi, is double[2], so your guess is correct